# HTML Image not displaying correctly in Chrome, but is displaying correctly in Safari and Firefox

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, alignment

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"> 

<img class="imageAAMP" src="catbanner.jpg" type="image/jpg" width="800" height="300" alt="Adios my petite croissant" style="position: relative;"/>

<img class="imageAAMP2" src="catbanner2.jpg" type="image/jpg" width="800" height="300" alt="Adios my petite croissant" style="position: absolute;"/>

<div>
```

And Here is my CSS

```
.container{
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 25px;
}

img.imageAAMP{
    width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    position: static
}

img.imageAAMP2{
    width: 800px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -800px;
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}

img.imageAAMP2:hover{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

The image is in the bottom left corner when it should be displaying on top of the first image. This is for the purpose of a on hover fade transition. On Safari and on Firefox, everything is working properly but it does not display correctly on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"> 

            <img class="imageAAMP" src="catbanner.jpg" type="image/jpg" width="800" height="300" alt="Adios my petite croissant" style="position: relative;"/>

            <img class="imageAAMP2" src="catbanner2.jpg" type="image/jpg" width="800" height="300" alt="Adios my petite croissant" style="position: absolute;"/>
<div>
```